# How many messages in Kafka Consumer come if I set pollTimeout to 1000ms

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-batch, spring-kafka

Implementing Kafka with Spring batch. developed Spring boot Application, My Kafka producer is continuously producing messages. I want to process these message in batches. but when I trigger the job, Job is continuously running. So I decided to add pollTimeout in KafkaItemReader. This way I'm able to stop my job. But how many messages will be coming in Kafka while triggering the Job. that I'm unable to find in google if I set pollTimeout to 1000ms how many message will come in KafkaItemReader.

Hint would be a helpful

@Bean
KafkaItemReader<String,String> item() { return new kafkaItemBuilder<String,String>().partitions(0).consumerproperties(prop).name(“reader”).savedata(true).topic(name).pollTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000).build()}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Batch processing is about fixed data sets. If your topic is a continuous stream of events, then a Spring Batch job is not a good choice for you, a streaming solution is more appropriate. Spring Batch expects your `ItemReader` to return `null` when the data source is exhausted, but in your case, the data source is never exhausted and that's why your job is never finished.

The timeout property will actually make the reader return `null` if no messages are received during that period.

Comment: Thanks for reply!. :) I have a question  that is there any way to make KafkaItemReader to run for certain Period of time?. So that It can process only that messages which are received  before the stop?. Because My requirement is to read messages from Kafka when I trigger the Spring batch.

Comment: Where should the reader start reading from when you run your job? From the beginning of the topic? From the last offset stored in kafka? From a custom offset?

Comment: For the first run it will start from the beginning. For Second run it should not start from the beginning because those messages are already processed. So i want to start from the certain offset, for the third run same I will start from certain offset. Start process those messages. My Springboot application will not go down during these run. I will  be triggering the job via RestController which I will Expose to trigger the Spring batch.

Comment: Thanks for the Help!. I will look into that :)

Answer (score 1):

The property is a timeout, not a record limit.

You can do some math against max.poll.records and the period of time between starting and stopping the consumer, but it'll only be an estimate, not an exact number because the poll timeout is only an upper bound that waits for the max poll record count

If you want to programmatically calculate number of processed messages, I'd suggest grabbing the offset difference or summing the consumed record count.

Comment: HI I have added that in my ConsumerProperties but it is batch job is continosuly running
I have mention My Bean Definition of KafkaItemReader

@Bean KafkaItemReader<String,String> item() { return new kafkaItemBuilder<String,String>().partitions(0).consumerproperties(prop).name(“reader”).savedata(true).topic(name).pollTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(1000).build()}

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Spring to tell you what you should be using, but Kafka, in general, is not meant to be part of a batch framework, and indeed will continuously run